# Scientific Linux: RAID5 unaccessible after netboot by mistake

Tags: linux, mount, hardware-raid, gpt, partition-table

A server running old scientific linux 6.0 suffered damage from an enabled netboot during reboot by trying to load some crap from an application server in the same subnet (I saw him stuck somewhere in an old novell setup procedure). Reboot ends in a grub menu, but no disks are available (can't find any partitions or kernel and just reinstall grub). OS and data partitions are on a single raid configured as two volumes with Raid 1 for the OS and RAID 5 for the data. I booted into a live system, and can see at least the volumes:

```
[root@livecd dev]# gdisk /dev/sdb 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.4
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT
Your answer: 2
Using GPT and creating fresh protective MBR.
Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-2): 1
Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
Partition unique GUID: BC2FE104-31B6-4E92-9DBF-B0C4DD581804
First sector: 999424 (at 488.0 MiB)
Last sector: 9765625855 (at 4.5 TiB)
Partition size: 9764626432 sectors (4.5 TiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: ''
```

Similar with parted:

```
[root@livecd dev]# parted /dev/sdb print
Warning: /dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
Model: SMC SMC2108 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 9995GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      512MB   5000GB  4999GB  ext4
 2      5000GB  9995GB  4995GB  ext4
```

/proc/partitions shows me only raw devices (sda + sdb), never devices which I could mount as ext4 (sdb1,sdb2). lsblk shows only the entire disks:

```
[root@livecd dev]# lsblk -t /dev/sdb
NAME ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED RQ-SIZE   RA
sdb          0    512      0     512     512    1 cfq       128  128
```

(Nothing from blkid). Is there any chance to get the data from the two sdb partitions, I get only their Partion unique GUID, but couldn't use these to mount the devices.

Many thanks for any hints how to access the data!